# Deferred chain crashing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, stack-overflow, jquery-deferred

This is small function that should be able to open and close a box. Opening and closing needs to take into account some CSS transitions, so I figured I can use `$.Deferred`.

Here's relevant code:

```
function Test(){

  // these are assigned Deferred objects during transitions
  this.opening = this.closing = false;

  this.isOpen = false;
  this.x = $('<div />').appendTo('body');
  this.x.width();
}

Test.prototype.open = function(){

  // box is already opening: return opening deferred
  if(this.opening)    
    return this.opening;

  // box is closing: this is the chain
  // that is supposed to wait for the box to close,
  // then open it again 
  if(this.closing)
    return this.closing.then((function(){
      return this.open();
    }).bind(this));

  // box is already open, resolve immediately
  if(this.isOpen)
    return $.when();    

  console.log('opening');
  this.opening = new $.Deferred();
  this.x.addClass('open');
  setTimeout((function(){
    this.opening.resolve();
    this.opening = false;
    this.isOpen = true;      
  }).bind(this), 1000);

  return this.opening;
};
```

The close() function is open() in reverse.

The problem appears when I try to close the box while it's being opened, or vice-versa. For example:

```
var t = new Test();

t.open(); // takes 1 second

// call close() after 0.05s
setTimeout(function(){
  t.close();
}, 50);
```

It appears there's a stack overflow happening or something like that. Does anyone know what's causing it?

The entire test code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uh1Lfgoo/), but with a higher timeout value so it doesn't crash Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notices several issues with your code:

- returning deferred objects instead of [promises](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/), you can execute .then() only on promises
- overriding deferred variable with bool value, I am using [deferred.state()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.state/) instead

This is the updated version of your code:

```
function Test(){
  this.opening = this.closing = false;
  this.isOpen = false;
  this.x = $('<div />').appendTo('body');
  this.x.width();
}

Test.prototype.open = function(){
  if(this.opening && this.opening.state() == 'pending')    
    return this.opening.promise();

  if(this.closing && this.closing.state() == 'pending')
    return this.closing.promise().then((function(){
      return this.open();
    }).bind(this));

  if(this.isOpen)
    return $.when();    

  console.log('opening');
  this.opening = new $.Deferred();
  this.x.addClass('open');
  setTimeout((function(){
    this.isOpen = true;    
    this.opening.resolve();
  }).bind(this), 1000);

  return this.opening.promise();
};

Test.prototype.close = function(){
  if(this.opening && this.opening.state() == 'pending') {
    console.log('opening is pending');
    return this.opening.promise().then((function(){
      console.log('opening is resolved');
      return this.close();
    }).bind(this));
  }

  if(this.closing && this.closing.state() == 'pending'){    
    console.log('closing is pending');
    return this.closing.promise();
  }

  if(!this.isOpen)
    return $.when();    

  console.log('closing');
  this.closing = new $.Deferred();
  this.x.removeClass('open');
  setTimeout((function(){
    console.log('closing resolved');
    this.closing.resolve();
    this.isOpen = false;
  }).bind(this), 1000);

  return this.closing.promise();  
};

var t = new Test();

t.open();

setTimeout(function(){
  t.close();
}, 15);
```

The output:

```
"opening"
"opening is pending"
"opening is resolved"
"closing"
"closing resolved"
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a tiny timing problem here. When you chain an open after a `.closing` promise, or a close after an `.opening` promise, these callbacks will be executed before the promises are removed:

> ```
> this.opening.resolve();
> this.opening = false;
> ```

The problem is that jQuery does execute synchronously from within the `resolve`, so the "retried" `this.open()` that was chained after the closing is called when the `.closing` promise is still there, and chains itself again, and again, and again…

You should be able to avoid that by doing

```
var def = this.opening;
this.opening = false;
this.isOpen = true;
def.resolve(); // trigger those who are waiting to immediately close it again
```

Comment: Thanks! Just realised that I can use a single Deferred if I combine both solutions http://jsfiddle.net/6o7qrcs4/

Answer (score 1):

I can't beat Bergi's explanation of the "stack overflow" issue, however I can't help thinking you would be better off not attempting to manage your own animation queue(s), which is both difficult and unnecessary.

With judicious use of jQuery's built-in [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/), [.dequeue()](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) and [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) methods, you can make a CSS transition behave exactly like a jQuery animation - integrated into an element's standard "fx" queue complete with its promise returned by the `.promise()` method.

```
function Test() {
    this.x = $('<div/>').appendTo('body');
    this.x.width();
    this.transitionEndString = 'webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend'; // cross-browser "transitionend" event names.
}

Test.prototype.open = function() {
    var that = this,
        x = this.x;
    x.queue('fx', function(next) {
        if(!x.hasClass('open')) {
            x.addClass('open').one(that.transitionEndString, next);
        } else {
            x.dequeue();
        }
    });
    return x.promise();
};
Test.prototype.close = function() {
    var that = this,
        x = this.x;
    x.queue('fx', function(next) {
        if(x.hasClass('open')) {
            x.removeClass('open').one(that.transitionEndString, next);
        } else {
            x.dequeue();
        }
    });
    return x.promise();
};
```

*The `else { x.dequeue(); }` clauses are necessary to force the promise to respond when a transition isn't invoked.*

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/odw6co9u/2/)**

Comment: The thing is that my real code is a bit more complicated. Besides that CSS transition, the box also has to take into account promises generated by plugins that hook/unhook themselves to/from elements within the box. But your solution is definitely the most elegant, I'll try to adapt it to my code. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you should do all the additional stuff in the code that calls `.open()` and `.close()`, which will remain low-level promise-returning methods. At least, that's what you should aim for.